# How to capture disk usage percentage of a partition as an integer?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, disk-usage

I would like a method to capture the disk usage of a particular partition, by using the directory where the partition is mounted. The output should just be an integer with no padding or following symbols, as I'd like to save it in a variable.

I've used `df --output=pcent /mount/point`, but need to trim the output as it has an unnecessary header, single space padding before the value, and a % symbol following the value like so:

```
Use%
 83%
```

In this case the output I would like would simply be `83`. I'm not aware of any drawbacks to using the output of `df`, but am happy to accept other methods that do not rely on it.

Comment: why not simply parse it?

Comment: I don't see a drawback either, you can remove the header with df then | tr -dc '0-9'

Comment: I stand corrected, I can't find the switch to remove the header from df.

Comment: I'd read the man page, and the info page and couldn't find it either @bc2946088, good shout to consider `tr`, I was getting my head in a mess with sed and awk ideas.

Comment: @bc2946088 printing only 0-9 with tr has the side effect of removing the header.

Comment: I assumed, I added it as an answer.  I was on my phone and couldn't test it, so I didn't want to offer up a non-working answer at first.

Comment: I've searched for removing header option,too. Basically GNU developers are reluctant to impleme it. There have been feature requests, and they just said no.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'd use...

```
df --output=pcent /mount/point | tr -dc '0-9'
```

Not sure if sed is faster, but I can't ever remember the sed values.

Comment: Using `time` to test it comes out as being just as fast as sed.

Comment: @Arronical unless your outputs are waaaaaaaaaaaay greater than 100%, I doubt you'd see much difference. :P

Comment: @Arronical What muru said; invocation time is likely to dominate.

Comment: In this instance, `tr` is easier to read than `sed`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's awk solution:

```
$ df --output=pcent /mnt/HDD | awk -F'%' 'NR==2{print $1}'   
 37
```

Basically what happens here is that we treat '%' character as field separator ( column delimiter ), and print first column $1 only when number of records equals to two ( the `NR==2` part )

If we wanted to use `bash`-only tools, we could do something like this:

```
bash-4.3$ df --output=pcent / | while IFS= read -r line; do 
>     ((c++)); 
>     [ $c -eq 2 ] && echo "${line%\%*}" ;
> done
 74
```

And for fun, alternative `sed` via capture group and `-r` for extended regex:

```
df --output=pcent | sed -nr '/[[:digit:]]/{s/[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]]+)%/\1/;p}'
```

Answer (score 6):

`sed` solution

```
df --output=pcent /mount/point | sed '1d;s/^ //;s/%//'
```

- `1d` delete the first line
- `;` to separate commands
- `s/^ //` remove a space from the start of lines
- `s/%//` remove `%` sign

Answer (score 6):

You can pipe to a `grep` that just extracts digits:

```
df --output=pcent /mount/point | grep -o '[0-9]*'
```

See it live:

```
$ echo "Use%
> 83%" | grep -o '[0-9]*'
83
```

Answer (score 1):

I came upon a server where --output=pcent was not yet implemented, so I used the normal output, filtered by column, followed by the regex: `df /mount/point | awk '{print $5}' | tr -dc '0-9'`

Comment: You should add -P or --portability to df; else if the /mount/point is to long it will line break and you get the wrong value.

Answer (score 1):

#### Bash two-step solution

Being somewhat of a bash (Borne Again SHell) fan the last year I thought I'd propose a solution using it.

```
$ DF_PCT=$(df --output=pcent /mnt/d)
$ echo ${DF_PCT//[!0-9]/}
5
```

- Line 1 captures `df` output to variable `DF_PCT`.
- Line 2 strips everything that is not a digit in `DF_PCT` and displays it on screen.
- Advantage over accepted answer is line feed after percentage (`5` in this case) is generated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an another solution:

```
df | grep /mount/point | awk '{ print $5 }' | cut -d'%' -f1
```